# texinfo: Can i write non-english info files? Such as Chinese, and how?

Tags: texinfo

The most gnu manual files use info, write a texinfo then makeinfo produce info files, it's great.

Can texinfo contain non-English characters then produce non-English infos or pdfs?

How can i write Chinese info manuals? What is the best solutions for non-English software manuals, documentations just one source files to info, man, html, and pdf. Thank you :)

Comment: i don't have any experience, but i would (1) write chinese text in utf8, including texinfo commands, with `\input texinfo.tex` at the start; (2) run using a plain xetex (i.e. command “`xetex my.info-file`”)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. A suggestion: Do us a favour and change your username to something more telling than "user1234".